# how to resign my keyboard when i stop typing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am having 2 textfields, first one name is username and other is password and i want when i enter on password and click outside on view my keyboard should return how is this possible.Can anybody help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to define a method on your superview's delegate (usually your current view controller):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.myPasswordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This code tells your password text field (named `myPasswordTextField` in this example) to resign its first responder status. The first responder is the item handling input at present; when an object resigns first responder, it gives up its input-taking powers, which for a text field means hiding the keyboard and finishing editing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to your `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:]`.

So in your tap gesture you can give the action which you want to perform.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the delegate methods of the UITextField

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

:)

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore: How this method is triggered when we click outside the keyboard on the view?

Comment: First implement the protocol in your .h file i.e `<UITextFieldDelegate>`, then set the textField's delegate to self either by `textField.delegate =  self` or you can just set it through IB. Right click on Text Field then make connection of Outlet delegate to it's File's Owner.

Comment: @Inder: Nope that is fine but how it hides keyboard when we click outside the keyboard?  If I am not wrong, we need to click return key of keyboard to trigger this event.  So we cannot use this method to hide keyboard on click of anywhere else apart from return key.

Comment: OK I'll check it tomorrow..
But you can try it.

Comment: Yeah this is not being called. By touching outside the UITextField. I thinks above solution will work

Comment: @Inder: Which above solution are you talking about?

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.myPasswordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}